# How do you align an equation with right arrow?

Tags: equations, align

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
  &&L'(\mu_{ij.})
  &= n_{ij.}-\sum_ke^{\mu+\lambda_i^I+...}\\
  &&&= n_{ij.}-\hat{\mu}_{ij.}=0\\
  &&\Rightarrow\quad
  &\hat{\mu}_{ij.}=n_{ij.}
\end{alignat}
```

Is there a way to nicely align the last the line in this equation?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something how this code, probably? But what is the fullstop in `\mu_{ij.}` (for example)?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{aligned}
  L'(\mu_{ij.})
  &= n_{ij.}-\sum_ke^{\mu+\lambda_i^I+ \cdots}\\
  &= n_{ij.}-\hat{\mu}_{ij.}=0\\
  &\Rightarrow \hat{\mu}_{ij.}=n_{ij.}
\end{aligned}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{aligned}
  L'(\mu_{ij.})
  &= n_{ij.}-\sum_ke^{\mu+\lambda_i^I+ \cdots}\\
  &= n_{ij.}-\hat{\mu}_{ij.}=0\\
  \Rightarrow \hat{\mu}_{ij.}&=n_{ij.}
\end{aligned}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**An edit on request of the user:**

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  L'(\mu_{ij.})
  &= n_{ij.}-\sum_ke^{\mu+\lambda_i^I+ \cdots}\\
  &= n_{ij.}-\hat{\mu}_{ij.}=0\\
  \Rightarrow \hat{\mu}_{ij.}&=n_{ij.}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, is there anyway I can label this? (and the . means summing over that factor)

Comment: @Ng123 Yes of course. Can you see if is it coherent with your request?

Comment: that is great thank you

Comment: @Ng123 Happy to help you and everyone.

Comment: @Ng123 If this suggestion suits for you, then please click the tick mark...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Very kind colleague, I thank you very much and with all my heart I extend my appreciation to a good person like you. Do not worry about the vote ... there is no need ... what is needed is to help each other without malice and especially without being evil. When I see good people like you, I get very emotional and cry.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks a lot to hear kind words like you (TeX great) people...

Comment: @MadyYuvi No no...I'm not great...remember this :-). I want to be last last last....of the people.